# Understanding of Linearly Independent for $n=2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

*Definition.* Let $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ be vectors. We say that $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ are linearly independent if for all scalars $\alpha _{1},...,\alpha _{n}$

$\alpha _{1}x_{1}+\ldots +\alpha _{n} x_{n}=0$

implies $\alpha _{1}=...=\alpha _{n}=0$.

*Simple case.* If $x_{1},x_{2}$ are not dependent, then $\alpha _{1},\alpha _{2}$ such that

$\alpha _{1}x_{1}+\alpha _{2}x_{2}=0$

and either $\alpha _{1} \neq 0$ or $\alpha _{2} \neq 0$. Say $\alpha _{1} \neq 0$. Then,

$x_{1}=-\dfrac {\alpha _{2}} {\alpha _{1}} x_{2}$.

My question is: The definitio says that $\alpha _{1}=...=\alpha _{n}=0$. Yet, the simple case says that either $\alpha _{1} \neq 0$ or $\alpha _{2} \neq 0$. I didn't understand. Can you explain?

Comment: negation of " all zero" means "at least one of them is non zero".

Comment: I didn't understant. The definition and the definition of simple case are equal, aren't they?

Comment: Where you have written, "If $x_1,x_2$ are not dependent", what you meant to write was, "If $x_1,x_2$ are dependent".

Comment: .."are dependent" instead ""are not dependent"..

Comment: Yes. Thanks....

Comment: So, does that clear things up, Kahler?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. Thanks.